# No converter for System.Double[] when using fitSharp 1.9

Tags: double, converters, fitsharp

When I run my FItnesse tests using fitSharp I am getting the "No converter for System.Double[]" error message near each value in capexAmounts column.
But the results are parsed and handled as doubles correctly - the DoesDepreciatedAmountsEqualToSpecifiedOnes method

What am I doing wrong?
Please, help

Here is my table:

```
| Run depreciation with different tangible setup |
| tangible | tangiblePercent | capexAmounts | does depreciated amounts equal to specified ones? |
| tan | 0 | [8, 5, 3.2, 1.6, 0.8] | [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] |
```

And here is my code:

```
public class RunDepreciationWithDifferentTangibleSetup
{
    public string Tangible { get; set; }
    public double TangiblePercent { get; set; }
    public double[] CapexAmounts { get; set; }

    public double[] DoesDepreciatedAmountsEqualToSpecifiedOnes()
    {
        return someArray;
    } }
```